# Many to One to Many doctrine, persist only one side

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, slim

I have a system with two tables and a join table. Reuniao have many Servidor and a Servidor have many Reuniao. For this I have a reuniao table, servidor table  and reuniaoservidor table. I want to persist a reuniao with many existing servidor, but I don't want to persist a servidor when a reuniao is persisted. The problem is...
When I try to persist a reuniao doctrine says to me:

"A new entity was found through the relationship 'SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Reuniao#servidores' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: SistemaIfnmg\Entity\ReuniaoServidor@000000006a69473200007f33ddb737e2. To solve this issue: Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}). If you cannot find out which entity causes the problem implement 'SistemaIfnmg\Entity\ReuniaoServidor#__toString()' to get a clue."

The Entyties:

Reuniao.php

```
namespace SistemaIfnmg\Entity;
use SistemaIfnmg\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="reuniao")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class Reuniao
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $titulo;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $descricao;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $data;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="SistemaIfnmg\Entity\ReuniaoServidor", mappedBy="reuniaofk")
 */
private $servidores;

public function __construct(){
    $this->servidores = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getTitulo()
{
    return $this->titulo;
}

/**
 * @param string $titulo
 */
public function setTitulo($titulo)
{
    $this->titulo = $titulo;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getDescricao()
{
    return $this->descricao;
}

/**
 * @param string $descricao
 */
public function setDescricao($descricao)
{
    $this->descricao = $descricao;
}

/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}

/**
 * @param string $data
 */
public function setData($data)
{
    $this->data = $data;
}

/**
 * Add servidores
 * @param \SistemaIfnmg\Entity\ReuniaoServidor $servidor
 * @return Reuniao
 */
public function addServidor(\SistemaIfnmg\Entity\ReuniaoServidor $servidor){
    $this->servidores[] = $servidor;
}

/**
 * Remove servidor
 *
 * @param \SistemaIfnmg\Entity\ReuniaoServidor $servidor
 */
public function removeServidor(\SistemaIfnmg\Entity\ReuniaoServidor $servidor){
    $this->servidores->removeElement($servidor);
}

/**
 * Get servidores
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getServidores(){
    return $this->servidores;
}


}

?>
```

Servidor.php

```
<?php

namespace SistemaIfnmg\Entity;
use SistemaIfnmg\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="servidor")
 */
class Servidor
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 * @var integer $id
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="nome", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $nome;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="sobrenome", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $sobrenome;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="cargo", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $cargo;
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="matricula", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $matricula;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set id
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * Get nome
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getNome()
{
    return $this->nome;
}

/**
 * Set nome
 *
 * @param string $nome
 */
public function setNome($nome)
{
    $this->nome = $nome;
}

/**
 * Get sobrenome
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSobrenome()
{
    return $this->sobrenome;
}

/**
 * Set sobrenome
 * @param string $sobrenome
 */
public function setSobrenome($sobrenome)
{
    $this->sobrenome = $sobrenome;
}

/**
 * Get cargo
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getCargo()
{
    return $this->cargo;
}

/**
 * Set cargo
 *
 * @param string $cargo
 */
public function setCargo($cargo)
{
    $this->cargo = $cargo;
}
/**
 * Get matricula
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getMatricula()
{
    return $this->matricula;
}

/**
 * Set matricula
 *
 * @param string $matricula
 */
public function setMatricula($matricula)
{
    $this->matricula = $matricula;
}




}

?>
```

ReuniadoServidor.php

```
<?php

namespace SistemaIfnmg\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * ReuniaoServidor
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reuniaoservidor", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_Reuniao_has_Servidor_Reuniao1_idx", columns={"reuniaofk"}), @ORM\Index(name="fk_Reuniao_has_Servidor_Servidor1_idx", columns= {"servidorfk"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ReuniaoServidor
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Reuniao", inversedBy="servidores", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reuniaofk", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $reuniaofk;


/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Servidor", inversedBy="servidores")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="servidorfk", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
 */
private $servidorfk;


/**
 * Get id
 * @return integer
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @param int $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * Get reuniaofk
 * @return \SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Reuniao
 */
public function getReuniaofk()
{
    return $this->reuniaofk;
}

/**
 * Set reuniaofk
 * @param \SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Reuniao $reuniaofk
 * @return ReuniaoServidor
 */
public function setReuniaofk($reuniaofk)
{
    $this->reuniaofk = $reuniaofk;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get servidorfk
 * @return \SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Servidor
 */
public function getServidorfk()
{
    return $this->servidorfk;
}

/**
 * Set servidorfk
 * @param \SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Servidor $servidorfk
 * @return ReuniaoServidor
 */
public function setServidorfk($servidorfk)
{
    $this->servidorfk = $servidorfk;
    return $this;
}



}

?>
```

I've been trying to fix this error for a long time, please, help??
Thanks a lot

Comment: why don't you add cascade={"persist", "remove"} as is written in exception you got

Comment: Thanks for reply!! I don't want to persist a Servidor, only a Reuniao!! So I add cascade persist in Reuniao only

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the entity that joins Reuniao to Servidor (the ReuniaoServidor entity) as Doctrine takes care of the join table for you. You just need to specify the join columns in the JoinTable mapping.

In Reuniao.php change the mapping of servidores to:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="SistemaIfnmg\Entity\Servidor")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="reuniao_servidor",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="ruuniao_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns{@ORM\JoinColumn(name="servidor_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *   )
 */
private $servidores;
```

also add a constructor that initializes the array for the collection

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->servidores = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

See https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional

Comment: Hey sir. Thanks for your answer and sorry for take too long to reply you. The project was deprecated but I got your thoughts and it will be very helpful on other projects. Thank you so much.

Comment: No probs, glad I could help :)